# How to find if there is any duplicate without using Find and Replace in MS WORD

Tags: excel, ms-word, duplicates, duplicate-data

In MS WORD,i have a table which consists about 9000-10000 rows with data. Now how do i find if there is any repeated data in this word file. Suppose,

```
 Route          Bus          Fare
 A to B       Trans A       1.5
 B to C       Trans B       2
 C to D       Trans C       1
 A to B       Trans D       1
```

So if any route is repeated i can add the transport to them. I know about "Find" feature of MS WORD,plz dont suggest me that as the amount of routes is around 10000 so typing and Searching for 10000 words individually is not a good idea. Please help me out if i can find out the duplicate data in any other way possible without typing and searching each of them individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could export the table to Excel and search for duplicates there. For example via:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/find-duplicate-values-fast-by-applying-conditional-formatting-HA102809491.aspx